# Forcefully send logged exceptions (non-fatal) to server with Crashlytics

Tags: android, logging, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I'm trying to use `Crashlytics.logException(Throwable t)`. The [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html?caught%20exceptions#) says that the no more than 8 messages can be logged in a single session and that these messages are sent to the server upon app restart. This doesn't seem convenient. How can I manually force these logs to be sent to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the question Dean. Right now it is not possible to force these logs to be sent in any other case except a restart. This is to prevent abuse on our end as well as limit the size of the upload required at restart. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer Todd! Can you please elaborate a bit before I accept your answer: Is there any other way to log an unexpected event using Crashlytics / Fabric and guarantee that the message is going to reach the server even if the user uninstalls the app after the first launch?

Comment: Following up on this @DeanPanayotov is that there is not a way to force the message through. If the user uninstalls the app after the first launch, the data would not be sent. Fortunately, we've found that to be very rare for users to do.

Comment: Try using https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-logging and write your own Exception.printStacktrace()